# Undefined variable error in PHP include file

Tags: php, variables, include, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined variable problem with PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058781/undefined-variable-problem-with-php-function)

Can someone tell me why I keep getting undefined variable error messages in my PHP include files?

```
<?php

$page = 1;

if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
  $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
}

function phpRocks() {
  require("includes/dostuff.php");
}

if ($search) {
  phpRocks();
}

?>
```

Then in dostuff.php:

```
<?php echo $page; ?>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: page in **/dostuff.php**
>   on line **61**

Attn down voters/close requesters: Doesn't show any research effort? How so? What else should I have added? I have been stumped over this for a half hour and cannot find any other posts that answer this question. Do I need to be a PHP expert in order to post questions (therefore I wouldn't be posting any questions!)??

Comment: Variable scope. You are declaring in the global scope, but open the template from a function with its own local var scope.

Comment: are you sure `$page` is getting set?

Comment: Where is `phpRocks()` called?

Comment: While both the author of this question and the author of the duplicate question have had the same problem, this question's title mentions PHP's include mechanism while the other doesn't. I had a problem with file inclusion which the duplicate question won't answer, therefore it is not a duplicate IMO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

mario's got it. Do this:

```
function phpRocks() {
    global $page;

    require("includes/dostuff.php");
}
```

Comment: Read up on scope Zoolander, thats your issue here

Comment: thanks for great answer

Answer (score 8):

You are including the file inside a function. Therefore the scope of all the included code is the scope of the function. The variable `$page` does not exist inside the function. Pass it in:

```
function phpRocks($page) {
    require "includes/dostuff.php";
}

phpRocks($page);
```

Comment: Why am I the only one here rooting for injection rather than `global` spaghetti?

Comment: Everyone else put Mario's comment into answer form for the easy reputation. You're the only one who actually added something relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution though. `$page` _should_ be a global variable here IMO ... it's a variable created in the global scope which an included file needs to use. The function call doesn't have anything to do with that. Plus he might want to pass "real" arguments to the function in the future, to be used outside of `dostuff.php`. This avoids confusion between the two.

Comment: @sgroves It has *everything* to do with the function. The function introduces a new scope, which is *good*. Any values that cross that scope boundary should be explicitly passed in and returned back out. Whatever happens inside the function with those values is irrelevant. It's also irrelevant that the included file "thinks" the variable is global, nothing changes for the included file either way. You're binding the function to surrounding scope it has no influence on. That's code coupling, which should always be avoided.

Comment: I believe that `global` is a better solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

add global var in you function like that

```
function phpRocks() {
  global $page;
  require("includes/dostuff.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the variable to global like this:

```
function phpRocks() {
global $page;           //set variable to global
require("includes/dostuff.php");
}
```